# Confusing compiler error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array with acceptable mime types:

```
export const frontend = { 
  ...
  zipMimeTypes: [
    "application/zip",
    "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "multipart/x-zip",
  ],
} as const;
```

I want to include it in another file and use it like so:

```
frontend.zipMimeTypes.includes(file.type)
```

However, my TS compiler is complaining about `file.type`

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '"application/zip" | "application/x-zip-compressed" |
> "multipart/x-zip"'.

I just do:

```
  [
    "application/zip",
    "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "multipart/x-zip",
  ].includes(file.type)
```

It works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `as const`. Instead, you can define an `interface` to use with `frontend`:

```
interface Frontend {
  zipMimeTypes: string[];
}
const frontend: Frontend = {
  zipMimeTypes: [
    "application/zip",
    "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "multipart/x-zip"
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Although forcing zipMimeTypes to be a string array will get rid of the error, you have now lost your typing for zipMimeTypes.

Instead I would create a type for your zipMimeTypes.

The advantages is that code-completion works nicely too.

```
export const frontend = { 
  zipMimeTypes: [
    "application/zip",
    "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "multipart/x-zip",
  ],
} as const;

type zipMimeType = typeof frontend.zipMimeTypes[number];

interface File {
    type: zipMimeType;
}

const file:File = {
    type: 'application/zip'
}

if (frontend.zipMimeTypes.includes(file.type)) {
  //etc.
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGZRTYyAmcAvHAN5wCwAUHHAF4CWYAsgwLbAAqAnmMKgC44AbWq1aAIgCGYMABsGCKTAYoA9IzASANGPHTZCpSvUgAtJrNI2YKP1TB8OvZLYBXOSrBTYa85ucaOABdXSoAXzgpVEQUdABuamoYXmB6JlYOHj5iOBS%20CAw4LBw8fAA6TUyuVNRhZDc2ACNgKGDEqmoGZFwoDCkENIAxBjk00hc81KEq9hq%20DvCkqiQ0TFHgARGx3Img2nzNuAByGXlFZVVkDSZj6iXOqgYigAoSnrLKjLns-nLuhByNz4fhvDblQ4ASkhZD0ajUwBgCHK92WQA)